# How to plot two labels on x-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have a data frame called `scenario_data` which looks like:

```
name        x    y
Scenario 1  0.5  0.5
Scenario 2  0.2  0.2
Scenario 3  0.8  0.2
Scenario 4  0.2  0.8
```

Below is the code I have used to generate a plot on a grid. What I want to do is have two x-axis labels at the extremes instead of one in the middle.

So towards the left side of the x-axis, I want it to say "Low" and on the right hand side I want it to say "High". Does anyone know how to do this simply?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

scenario_data <- read.csv("scatter_plot.csv", header = T)

tiff("scenario_plot.tiff", units="in", width=5, height=5, res=300)

scenarios_plot <- ggplot(scenario_data,
                         aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#93358D", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Figure 1: Four \n Scenarios",
       x = "Middle",
       y = "Scale of \n Intervention",
 

scenarios_plot +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = name),
                   box.padding = 0.35,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = "grey50") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        axis.line = element_line(arrow = 
                                   arrow(angle = 15, length = 
                                           unit(0.15, "inches"), 
                                         type = "closed")))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `scale_x_continuous()` with `breaks` and `labels`. Try this: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.2, 0.8), labels = c("Low", "High")) +` Here are some examples: https://www.statology.org/ggplot2-scale_x_continuous/

Comment: Thanks @David. The problem with this is that it converts the x and y labels to "x" and "y" respectively once `theme_classic()` is applied. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Hi again @HelpMe, Here is what worked for me: in your `labs()` part, make `x="",`. After `theme_classic() +`, put `scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.2, 0.8), labels = c("Low", "High")) +`. Then remove or comment out `axis.text.x=element_blank(),` and `axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),`. I think the problem was because `axis.text.x` and `axis.ticks.x` were wiped out with `element_blank()`. Note that you can also use `range(scenarios_plot$x)` to pass to `scale_x_continuous(breaks=)`.

Comment: The difference between `labs(x="")` and `labs(x=NULL)` is that in the first, there is blank space reserved for a not-visible axis label, unused space.

Comment: @David, post as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me @HelpMe:

And a big thanks to @r2evans for the note about `""` versus `NULL`. I didn't know that!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

#read in data as "scenario_data" and create tiff; steps omitted

#initial plot that removes the x axis label
scenarios_plot <- ggplot(scenario_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(colour = "#93358D", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Figure 1: Four \n Scenarios",
       x = NULL,
       y = "Scale of \n Intervention")

#second plot with annotations
scenarios_plot +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = name),
                   box.padding = 0.35,
                   point.padding = 0.5,
                   segment.color = "grey50") +
  theme_classic() +
#label the ticks as desired on the x axis
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.2, 0.8), labels = c("Low", "High")) +
#alternatively scale_x_continuous(breaks=range(scenarios_plot$x), labels = c("Low", "High")) +

#preserve the statements that allow the x axis ticks and annotations to appear
  theme(
#axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0),
#axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        axis.line = element_line(arrow = 
                                   arrow(angle = 15, length = 
                                           unit(0.15, "inches"), 
                                         type = "closed")))
```

See how this goes. I changed the "Scenario" labels slightly.

[image: Desired resulting plot; I changed the labels slightly]